# Find the expected number E of games in the tournament.

Tags: probability, random-variables

The probability of team A winning any game is 1/2. Suppose A plays B in a tournament (and there are no ties). The first team to win two games in a row or three games wins the tournament. Find the expected number E of games in the tournament.

```
AA       (1/2)(1/2)=(1/4)
BAA      (1/2)(1/2)(1/2)=(1/8)
ABAA     (1/2)(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)=(1/16)
BABAA    (1/2)(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)=(1/32)
```

So E(X)= 2( (2)(1/4) + (3)(1/8) + (4)(1/16) + (5)(1/32) ) = 2.5645 or 41/16

But the answer in my book is 23/8 or approximately 2.9

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an upper limit on the number of games in total?

Comment: @numbermaniac It just asks what I have stated. Nothing more is asked.

Comment: @numbermaniac:  after five games one side will have won at least three, so that is an upper limit.

Comment: @RossMillikan ah yes, I only saw the "two games in a row" and missed that bit somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not modify your post after you received answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your probabilities do not sum to $\frac 12$ so you have done something wrong.  You have missed ABABA

Now you didn't add the numerator correctly.  Putting everything inside the multiplication by $2$ over $16$ we get $4\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 3 +4+5=8+6+4+5=23$

Comment: I got mixed up and kept thinking that was a tie.